# how to add fade effect to change_image function

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, function, fade

I have an image array with a change image function in javascript. The function is called out by an image linked to an a link with (href="javascript:change_image(1) in the html.

The script works fine when loaded in the html but I would like to add a fade effect to it so that each image fades out and the new one fades in. Could somebody put me in the right direction?

I really appreciate it..

the script:

```
var Image = new Array("Img/1.jpg","Img/2.jpg","Img/3.jpg","Img/4.jpg","Img/5.jpg","Img/6.jpg");

var Image_Number = 0;
var Image_Length = Image.length - 1;

function change_image(num){ 

Image_Number = Image_Number + num;

if (Image_Number>Image_Length){

    Image_Number = 0;
}
if (Image_Number<0){

    Image_Number = Image_Length;
}


document.slideshow.src= Image[Image_Number];

return false;
}
```

Comment: jQuery is permitted or only JavaScript is required ?

Comment: As @Arpit suggests, [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/) would be a really easy way to implement this. There are also ways to implement this with CSS transitions which would perform better, but you might have to change the way you're swapping images to make that work.

Comment: Jquery is permitted. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

HTML:

```
<img id="image" src="Img/1.jpg"><br>
<span id="change_image">Change image!</span>
```

JS:

```
var images = ["Img/1.jpg", "Img/2.jpg", "Img/3.jpg", "Img/4.jpg"];

$(document).ready(function(){
    var image_number = 0;
    // Click handler for "change image" link
    $("#change_image").click(function(){
        // Get number of next image (loop)
        image_number = (image_number + 1) % images.length;
        // Make sure the image is loaded (if not, preload it)
        $("<img>").attr("src", images[image_number]).load(function(){
            // As soon as the next image is loaded, fade out the current one...
            $("#image").fadeOut(function(){
                // ...and fade in the new image :)
                $(this).attr("src", images[image_number]).fadeIn();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

[DEMO (JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/ShHhS/1/)

Comment: Yes that looks right! There are two things that still need to be solved: (1)  the function load needs to be loaded by an image not a span (2) I noticed that the hand logo doesn't show on mouseover the span (soon to be image). I'd like this show.

Comment: (1) You can attach the click handler to any HTML element you want, you only have to adjust the CSS selector which is passed to jQuery. I've updated my answer and the JSFiddle now so it works without the `span`. Alternatively, you could replace the click handler (the line with `$("#change_image").click...`) with a regular function and use the `onclick` attribute (similar to your original code). (2) This can be done with CSS: `cursor: pointer`

Comment: Please upload your first answer : the function needs to be loaded by a different image (not the image on the array itself). Therefore your answer suggesting a span to trigger the function is more useful for me. many thanks

Comment: Ok, reverted to the original answer. However, you should easily be able to adapt my example code so it fits your needs - it's always the same pattern. If you're not familiar with the jQuery syntax, you could read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_syntax.asp) and [this](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/).